# Using django-registration package (hmac method), how to assign a user to a specific user model?

Tags: django, django-registration

I want to apologize in advance for not being clear enough, I am in the process of learning Django.

My project utilizes django-registration package, hmac method. It has different types of Users, like: Teachers and Students. Each of these types has its own model, like:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="courses")
```

The question I have is how to assign a user to the Student model when the user hits activation link that was sent to him by django-registration? Should I override "[ActivationView](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration/blob/2.2/registration/views.py)"? What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: You will need a single parent model for user. (Like AuthUser), this will be the user with the stored activation status.

Comment: Thank William, I really want to see a more detailed answer, since many things in django are still obscure to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to override save method in custom User model

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    Student.objects.create(user=self)
```